# Magento getProductUrl function getting same url for all products

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

I'm trying get product datas using `getmodel()`. My code is,

```
//$product_ids = $this->getproducts();
$product_ids = array(0=>1, 1=>2, 2=>3); 
echo'<pre>';  
 $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
 foreach($product_ids as $id) {
    $data = $model->load($id); 
    echo $id;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $data->getProductUrl();
    echo '<br>';
    echo $data->getName();
    echo '<br>';    
 }
```

I can get the data's of each product name and url. Name is correctly displayed but the **url** I'm getting the same url of first product for each product in loop. But the looping is fine.

And I tried with `getUrlPath()` it is also getting same url

And if I directly pass the id (not in loop) then I can get the correct url. Like

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
echo $model->getProductUrl();
```

Is that any caching issue..? (But caching is disabled). these things make me mad.

And If used below code then I can get the correct url (loop),

```
    foreach($product_ids_ids as $id) {
  $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('product_url')
           ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
           ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $id)
           ->load();

foreach($_item as $product){
    echo $product->getProductUrl();
    echo $product->getName();
}
}
```

This is not making any sense. I tried reindex, checked the flat catalog -> it is not enabled. But I cannot find out what's reason. And I checked admin -> catalog -> Url rewrites having empty - No datas. May be this is the reason.

Any one can tell the reason please ?

Comment: bizarre, using the exact same code (as your first code block) this works fine for me.  Try setting $data = false; after the final <br /> ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Elavarasan**

```
Its because you are using something horrible like below as loop goes on:
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1)->load(2)->load(3);
```

Here is what i roughly wrote, but it should work. Try it.

```
$product_ids = array(
        0=>1,
        1=>2,
        2=>3,
        3=>4,
        4=>5
    );

//Why to load product object each time? Instead get collection, only one database call.
$productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalo/product")->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$product_ids));
foreach($productCollection as $_product) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "<br/>Id : ".$_product->getId();
    echo "<br/>Name : ".$_product->getProductUrl();
    echo "<br/>Url : ".$_product->getName();
    echo "</pre>";
}
```